# Split a string into a bunch of lines in awk

Tags: linux, awk, gawk

I have several files like this containing 1 line:

```
CHTACAUSYDUYADUSAYUDYASUDYUASYDUADSYAUDYSUAYDUASDUBASUDASUBDYUASYUCJUAYAYCYUAUAHUAHUHAUHDIADJIOAJDIAHDUADIAJDOJADIJAHUDHAA
```

I need to split it into several lines each adding 1 character:

```
CHTACAUSYDUYAD
CHTACAUSYDUYADU
CHTACAUSYDUYADUY
CHTACAUSYDUYADUYA
CHTACAUSYDUYADUYAD
```

I am trying with this awk code:

```
more +2 file | awk '
{ 
    split($0, chars, "")
    for (i=1; i <= length($0); i++) {
        printf("%s\n", chars[i])
    }
}'
```

but it only prints 1 character per line.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks problem is in `split` - that breaks your string against empty regexp. So you need `substr` instead:

> substr(s, i [, n])      Return the at most n-character substring of s starting at i.  If n is omitted, use the rest of s.

Not perfectly clear criteria of first line generation, but let me assume it is done by **initial** length = 15

```
{
    initial = 15
    for (i=initial; i <= length($0); ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", substr($0, 1, i))
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted. Thank you for your helping!